# When does Emirates release its economy saver tickets?

Tags: budget, tickets, emirates

I'm on the Emirates website and I'm looking at ticket booking, as far into the future as the website will allow me, and the Economy Saver tickets are showing as all booked up.

I'm guessing that this is because people have snapped them up as soon as they were available.

So my question is: on what date does Emirates release its Economy Saver tickets?

E.g. perhaps it's a particular date in the each month for the whole month a year ahead? Or something like that?

(Or alternatively maybe the seats are showing as 'sold out' but actually the cheapest tickets are unavailable because I'm too early and they haven't yet been released - if that's the case I'd still be interested in knowing the date when they will be released).

In a [previous answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14559/the-release-date-of-the-cheap-airline-tickets-for-a-given-day) I can see choster has written:

> Most of the major international network carriers update their schedules daily, and will release seats from 330-360 days out.

but it would be useful to get more specific info, if it's available.

Answer (score 4):

There is no etched in stone schedule.  Airlines open up flights for booking 330 days ahead (a few earlier, but 330 is the most common).  They tend to not offer a lot of seats in their cheapest fare buckets initially, as they prefer to sell seats at a higher fare.

If seats are selling well on a flight, they might not release any of the cheapest fare bucket.  If sales are sluggish, they will open up some seats at the lower cost fares.

Available seats within a fare bucket can be adjusted daily, weekly, monthly, maybe for all flights, maybe for only a couple of dates.  It is a complex process that few outside the industry can decipher.

If they had a strict schedule then folks would wait until a certain date to book the cheapest seats.  So they deliberately keep you guessing.